# Verizon VPN to AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, cisco, amazon-vpc, cisco-vpn

I was wondering if Verizon can terminate their VPN to AWS VPC ?

Our existing setup has Cisco Router (CSR1000V) running on EC2 instance and Verizon VPN is terminated on the public IP of the EC2 instance. That's how the Verizon traffic enter AWS VPC.

Comment: Is Direct Connect an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, VZW can terminate their MPN solution to virtual hardware within AWS.